# Route mail traffic across wireguard tunnel

Tags: linux, iptables, docker, wireguard

I'm setting up a mail server (mailcow) and this is the current infrastructure:

[image]

VPS wireguard ip tables

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 42795 -j ACCEPT
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A PREROUTING ! -s 10.0.0.2 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.2
-A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

VM on-prem wireguard

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [584:49760]
:INPUT ACCEPT [584:49760]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1097:91741]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 18442 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.27.30.127:8442
-A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 10953 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.27.30.101:10953
-A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.27.30.129:1053
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.27.30.129:1053
-A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 17326 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.27.30.101:17326
-A PREROUTING -s 10.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.27.30.130:25
-A PREROUTING -s 10.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.27.30.130:465
-A PREROUTING -s 10.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.27.30.130:587
-A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

It works great for receiving email (ie. all inbound traffic from internet to local servers) but to be able to send email I need to route outbound traffic from the mail VM (or posfix docker container) ports 25,465 & 587 to internet across wireguard tunnel.

I tried a hodgepodge of things but none of them worked.